# Intellij + Gradle, ignore errors in other modules and just test the current module

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a project which is being refactored. But right now I wanna unit test a class which has changed a lot and caused other dependencies to break.

Can I run tests for this class alone without getting errors from the other classes.
I'm getting errors in *compileJava* task from Gradle.

I searched the *web* about a *Build, no error check* option in Intellij but I'm running Gradle as a build tool.

I'm running Intellij IDEA 2022.1 (Ultimate Edition) and Gradle v7.4.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle does not support such kind of compilation that would proceed on errors.

As a workaround, you can [switch to IDE's build](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#delegate_build_actions) in stead of gradle's in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Build and run using** and use "Build, no error check" approach. Then build project and run tests using IDE's builder and runner.